# How to load tfrecord in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, tfrecord

How to use tfrecord with pytorch?

I have downloaded "Youtube8M" datasets with video-level features, but it is stored in tfrecord.
I tried to read some sample from these file to convert it to numpy and then load in pytorch. But it failed.

```py
    reader = YT8MAggregatedFeatureReader()
    files = tf.gfile.Glob("/Data/youtube8m/train*.tfrecord")
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
        files, num_epochs=5, shuffle=True)
    training_data = [
        reader.prepare_reader(filename_queue) for _ in range(1)
    ]

    unused_video_id, model_input_raw, labels_batch, num_frames = tf.train.shuffle_batch_join(
        training_data,
        batch_size=1024,
        capacity=1024 * 5,
        min_after_dequeue=1024,
        allow_smaller_final_batch=True  ,
        enqueue_many=True)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        label_numpy = labels_batch.eval()
        print(type(label_numpy))
```

But this step have no result, just stuck for a long while without any response.

Comment: a shameless self-plug: https://github.com/jongwook/tfrecord_lite

Comment: Thanks,@lyomi, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:  [TFRecord reader for PyTorch](https://github.com/vahidk/tfrecord.git)

Answer (score 3):

One work around is to use tensorflow 1.1* eager mode or tensorflow 2+ to loop through the dataset(so you can use var len feature, use buckets window), then just
`torch.as_tensor(val.numpy()).to(device)` to use in torch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DALI library to load the tfrecords directly in a PyTorch code.

You can find out, how to do it [in their documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dali/archives/dali_170/user-guide/docs/examples/frameworks/pytorch/pytorch-various-readers.html).

Answer (score 0):

I cooked up this:

```py
class LiTS(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, filenames):
        self.filenames = filenames

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.filenames)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        volume, segmentation = None, None
        if idx >= len(self):
            raise IndexError()
        ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames[idx:idx+1])
        for x, y in ds.map(read_tfrecord):
            volume = torch.from_numpy(x.numpy())
            segmentation = torch.from_numpy(y.numpy())

        return volume, segmentation
```